# Gettting timeout error while finding element username for twitter

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the twitter site to login to twitter. while scraping the site for username, using XPath, I am getting this exception:

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

This is my function. I have tried changing the values of wait condition as well, yet same timeout exception is coming. Can somebody explain me why this error is there when we use long XPath and how can I resolve this.

```
def tweet_At_provider(self):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    twitter_driver = self.driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")
    username = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')))\
    .send_keys("*****")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Root cause of the issue:** Your XPath expression to locate <kbd>username</kbd> element is incorrect. Try the below locator strategy:

```
username = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "text")))
```

**Working code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
username = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "text")))
username.send_keys("mic test 123")
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
The Xpath is wrong, use the below mechanism.

self.browser.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 30)
self.browser.get("https://www.twitter.com/login")
username_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "text")))
username_input.send_keys("send username here")
```

Comment: Isn't this the duplicate answer? Exact same solution is already in my answer!

Comment: No, I used a different expected condition method. let me know whether ur issue is sorted or not?

Comment: Expected condition, `visibility_of_element_located` or `element_to_be_clickable` won't make much difference to the root cause of the OP's issue. Root cause is locator strategy and not `waits`. I consider it a duplicate answer.